# React : Context update at the second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-context

I encounter a little problem on my react script when I try to update context.

I have button that, when clicking on it is supppose to update the context, but it works only at the second click :

[image]
Here is the code of my component :

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { MdDelete } from 'react-icons/md'
    import AppContext from '../../../../../../../context/AppContext'


    const DeleteAttribute = (props) => {
      const context = useContext(AppContext)

      const handleClick = () => {
          context.app.insertApiResponse('test')

          console.log(context.app.lastApiResponse)
      }

      return (
          <div className="item skr-flex row centered-v" onClick={ handleClick }>
              <MdDelete className="skr-icon delete mr-s"/>
              <span className="font-700">Supprimer</span>
          </div>
      )
    }
    export default DeleteAttribute
```

I've also try to use `Appcontext.Consumer` but the same result appear.

I don't understand why it work only at the second click on the button and it would be very helpful for me if someone could give me an answer.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a value before the api has responded with any data. On the second run the data in `context.app.lastApiResponse` has value from the first run. So what you need to do is use `then()`, this waits for the data and then executes the code inside

Not sure exactly how you other code looks but you can try something like this:

```
const DeleteAttribute = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(AppContext)

  const handleClick = () => {
      context.app.insertApiResponse('test').then(() => {
    console.log(context.app.lastApiResponse)
  })   
}
```